# save string to a binary file in python

Tags: python, string, binary, save

I would like to know a very basic thing of Python programming as I am a very basic programmer right now): how can I save a result (either a list, a string, or whatever) to a file in Python?
I've been searching a lot, but I couldn't find any good answer to this.
I was thinking about the ".write ()" method, but (for instance) it seems not working with strings, neither I know what it is supposed to do though.
So, my situation is that I have binary fils, which I would like to edit, therefore I found easy to convert them to strings, modify them, and now I'd like to save them i) back to binary files (jpegs images) and ii) in the folder I want.
How would I do that? Please I need some help.

**UPDATE**

Here is the script I'm trying to run:

```
import os, sys

newpath= r'C:/Users/Umberto/Desktop/temporary'
if not os.path.exists (newpath):
    os.makedirs (newpath)

data= open ('C:/Users/Umberto/Desktop/Prove_Script/Varie/_BR_Browse.001_2065642654_1.BINARY', 'rb+')
edit_data= str (data.read () )
out_dir= os.path.join (newpath, 'feed', 'address')

data.close ()


# do my edits in a secon time...

edit_data.write (newpath)

edit_data.close ()
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

**UPDATE_2**

I tried to use pickle module to serialize my binary file, modify it and save it at the end, but still not getting it to work... This is what I've been trying so far:

```
import cPickle as pickle
binary= open ('C:\Users\Umberto\Desktop\Prove_Script\Varie\_BR_Browse.001_2065642654_1.BINARY', 'rb')
out= open ('C:\Users\Umberto\Desktop\Prove_Script\Varie\preview.txt', 'wb')
pickle.dump (binary, out, 1)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-981b17a6ad99> in <module>()
----> 1 pprint.pprint (pickle.dump (binary, out, 1))

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\copy_reg.pyc in _reduce_ex(self, proto)
     68     else:
     69         if base is self.__class__:
---> 70             raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
     71         state = base(self)
     72     args = (self.__class__, base, state)

TypeError: can't pickle file objects
```

Another thing I didn't get is that if I am supposed to create a file to poit to (in my case I had to create "out", otherwise I wouldn't have the right arguments for the pickle method) or it's not necessary.
Hope I'm getting close to the solution.

P.S.: I tried also with pickle.dumps (), not achieving a nicer result though...

Comment: In what way does `write` not work with strings? In any case, if you want to save lists etc to a file, it's a good idea to use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), but that's entirely different than working with a JPEG or another binary file

Comment: I will edit my question so that You can see what I'm trying to do, even if I know the part where I use the '.write ()' module is totally wrong because I still don't know how to use it...

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying? It is impossible to answer the question otherwise.

Comment: You needed to open a file handle to write to- something like `outf = open(newpath, "w")`, then do `outf.write(edit_data)`, then `outf.close()`. You don't call `write` from the string itself. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're opening a binary file and saving another binary file you could do something like this:

```
with open('file.jpg', 'rb') as jpgFile:
    contents = jpgFile.read()

contents = (some operations here)

with open('file2.jpg', 'wb') as jpgFile:
    jpgFile.write(contents)
```

Some comments:

- 'rb' and 'wb' means read and write in binary mode respectively. More info on why 'b' is recommended when working with binary files [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).
- Python's [with statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) takes care of closing the file when exiting the block.

If you need to save lists, strings or other objects, and retrieving them later, use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) as others pointed out.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if you gave at least a tiny bit of explanation and/or links to documentation. I'm sure many beginners will wonder what the magic `'rb'` and `'wb'` strings are for, for instance.

Comment: this is a much better answer now. Nice job.

Comment: Thanks to this answer and to David Robinson commenr I succeded in managing it (by the .write () method)! The only thing that still remains unclear is why when I open the two binary files I have (the original one and the new one) in a hex editor, they look slightly different although I didn't edit anything (because mine was just a try to understand how the saving procedure works). Any clue? Thanks again for Your precious efforts!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard python module named "pickle".

You can read about it here: [pickle documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)

Read and write any data structure will be very easy

```
pickle.dump(obj, file_handler) # for serialize object to file
pickle.load(file)              # for deserialize from file
```

or you can serialize to string: pickle.dumps(..) and load from it: pickle.loads(...)

Comment: I think I will document on the pickle module, as my jpegs are in binary formats and when I try to run the script as You suggest, it outputs an error, saying "TypeError: must be string or buffer, not file". Thank You anyway!

Comment: of course you can't load data from other formats with pickle. They loads only files saved with pickle.dump, and store data in specified format. Your first question was "how can I save and load strings and other structures" - pickle is the easiest way

Comment: I red the documentation, and tried to pickle my file, receiving an error. I'm updating my question so that You would know what I've been trying.

Comment: Ok, for your problem you need to use Diego Herranz answer. Because pickle save data in its own format, and this is not what you want.